# How to store data from a method after calling it?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to store the data in a variable in the CongressStats that I fetched from the printPartyBreakdownInSenate method without "capturing" it and returning the value somehow.

```
public class CongressStats
{
private int congressNum;

public void printPartyBreakdownInSenate() {
     CongressDataFetcher.fetchSenateData(congressNum);
 }
```

here is the method I calling from.

```
public static String fetchSenateData(int congressNum)
{
    return fetchCongressData(Chamber.SENATE, congressNum);
}
```

Comment: store it in a String variable like this: String rc = fetchSenateData(....

Answer (score 0):

The method has a return type for String objects, so you could try something like so:

```
    int yourValueHere = 0;
    String store = fetchSenateData(yourValueHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is "return" statement so it is last statement in your method and when method is gone all internal variables are gone too. You can "store" value somewhere outside of the method. For example in class variables. something like this:

```
class Test {
String storedValue; 
   public static String fetchSenateData(int congressNum)
    {
        return storedValue=fetchCongressData(Chamber.SENATE, congressNum);//<--Store this
    }
}
```

This is possible because result of assigning operator "=" is the value assigned in this operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public static String fetchSenateData(int congressNum) {
  Integer i = new Integer(congressNum);
  if (map.containsKey(i) {
    return map.get(i);
  } else {
    String s = fetchCongressData(Chamber.SENATE, congressNum);
    map.put(i, s);
    return s;
  }
}
```